# How can I convert a shader displacement to a texture map?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, geometry, shader-nodes

I'm looking to convert the distortion and noise nodes into a mesh that I can sculpt/transfer over to unity to use as a landscape for a game I'm working on, but every suggestion I've found elsewhere and tried hasn't worked. I followed a procedural landscape tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVNZD3JTOfw) that showed the shader node set up to be something like this:

[image: Shader nodes]

My shader nodes achieve the effect I'm looking for in render preview with cycles, but its almost like they "don't exist" anywhere else in the project (UV editor is completely blank, the differences in "elevation" shown in render preview aren't selectable). I tried doing a diffuse bake in render settings to an image texture node that ended up just producing this:[image]

Even though the render preview still shows the distortion and noise properly:
[image]

There are also no modifiers shown in the modifier properties tab, and adding a multires modifier didn't seem to do anything either. I'm really happy with the way the landscape looks in render preview, and I hope I don't just have to make it using only modifiers (although if that's the only way then so be it), so any recommendations would be most appreciated, as I'm still relatively new to blender (at least as far as making my own models/sculpting/anything that isn't just downloading a model and animating it). I also apologize if this question has been asked already and I didn't see it, I don't think I saw anyone else on here with the same issue but I could be wrong.

Comment: You're quite right. They don't exist. Shader _Displacement_  (and the possible accompanying adaptive subdivision) happens at render-time. Your displacement is height-only .. you could bake the height, or the height-difference from your geometry, out into an image and use it in a Displacement modifier. The resolution of the mesh would have to be quite high to capture it, though.. Is this displacement incremental on an already 'hilly' geometry?

Comment: Here, Blender Secrets explain how you can bake the map: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qh6fbRzViM0

Comment: @Robin Betts The displacement was put on to a completely flat base plane, no extra geometry was added, except for some spots where i pulled the plane down slightly to show more of the displacement, but that was done after the displacement and noise nodes were added

Comment: @moonboots thank you for the suggestion, I tried following the tutorial, unfortunately when I delete the principle bdsf the terrain/displacement got deleted with it, and I was left with a completely black flat plane

Comment: once you've baked, use a subdivided plane, give it a Displace modifier with the baked map as texture

Comment: @moonboots Ok my bad, I'm just dumb haha, that worked a treat and I was able to get the height map from it onto a plane as geometry, thank you thank you so much!

Comment: And thank you as well @Robin Betts for your help, it and you both are very much appreciated!

Comment: I renamed the titled as I thought it was a bit clearer what you were asking. Feel free to revert :)